# In Java, why does type casting of a character to an integer NOT extend the sign bit

Tags: java, upcasting

In Java a bitwise operation causes type casting to integer and also causes sign extension. For instance the following is expected:

```
byte b = -1;
System.out.println(b >> 1);//-1
```

In Java chars are encoded in UTF-16 and each unit is represented with 2 bytes.

```
char c = 0xFFFF; //I assume now the sign bit is 1.
System.out.println(c >> 1);//32767 ???? WHY
```

I was expecting -1 instead of 32767. Why is the sign not extended during the type cast before the bitwise operation is applied? Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `char` is unsigned - `0xFFFF` really has a value of 65535

Comment: I don't want to be picky but `0xFFFF` is 65535

Answer (score 3):

It works like that because of [widening primitive conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25214) that is performed on shift arguments. Namely there's no information loss, including the sign of the type being converted.